# Harry Potter Patronus Sound Effect

Tags: magical

I Have some troubles to design some sound effect, i'm working on a movie where the Magic has a big place. In this movie there is a character who uses his magic wand in order to protect himself against creatures just like Harry potter did with the patronus against dementors.

My Goal is to create a sound effect quite similar to the patronus sound effect in the Harry Potter movie :

,because the image is quite the same, a white light which is growing and then starts to be a protective shield against those creatures.

Waiting for your answers, Thank you all
Have a nice day !

Comment: What sound effect do you mean exactly? There's not actually that much SFX in there, it's mostly the choir and horn in the score that's used.

Comment: Yes, time and description of the sound make this a bit easier.

Comment: It's a White Light Created by the wand, the light is growing just like the patronus in HP, then the light takes all the image and its stops the creatures from the Hero, just like they are Fixed by the spell. The Light is growing but there is not throwing spell against the creatures, just a light growing.

Comment: Nice subject. What have you already tried yourself? Where does it fail and is there an overal idea/concept of what the sfx can consist of?

Comment: I've tried a lot of things, actually technologic sounds don't work like I thought, but I improve that and I ma near of what I was waiting for with big énergie waves, electric sparkles in the background, some big processed horn.

Answer (score 1):

To me, if I understand your question correctly it sounds like a combo of:

- Choir Sounds
- The sound of crows with some pitch processing fed through a doppler plugin (like wave's Doppler)
- A third sound that sound not unlike kitchen knife honing iron with a bit of processing

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! By crows you mean the birds? Sorry for my english ^^

Answer (score 1):

Angelic choir (try Spectrasonic's Symphony of Voices) + ripping a piece of paper + blade sharpener effects with a flanger/phaser effect.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but whatever. 1:14-1:15 you can hear it clearly. Seems everyone is trying not to understand the question. The knife/crow sound is the sound of the Dementor's screaming from the effects of the spell.

I would take an oscillating fan, record it, edit the loudnesss so that the sound file has obvious fading in and out of loudness. Import audio into program of choice, then: bass boost, paulstretch (maybe?), reverb. Change tempo if needed and adjust pitch to liking.